# Silverlight: Using System.Windows.Browser.HttpUtility

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, silverlight, http-headers

I am trying to write a Silverlight application with a given ASP.NET API to connect to a database. How do I translate the following to my Silverlight application? Since I cannot include System.Web, I cannot use the HttpUtility to parse the string as shown in the code below:

```
    static async void CreateConnection()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
            = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{username}:{password}")));

        query["subscription-key"] = "";

        var uri = "http://somedatabase.net/api" + query;

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek13PortableHttpClientMakesPortableLibrariesMoreUseful.aspx) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you on the right track.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass"); // this can be any ICredential type, I just used NetworkCredential as example

var qString = HtmlPage.Document.QueryString;
var uri = new Uri("http://somedatabase.net/api/" + qString["subscription-key"]);

client.OpenReadCompleted += SomeEventHandler;
client.OpenReadAsync(uri);
```